# Prevent entry of a value other than suggested with Twitter Typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead

I'm using Twitter Typeahead (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js) in various places on a form to ease entry of values into text inputs. However I have one input where I want to disallow entry of a value other than that suggested by typeahead.

Although I would traditionally use a  for such a task the Typeahead provides a much better user interface.

At present I have the following code to initiate the Typeahead:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        prefetch: {
            url: '/assets/data/countries.json',
            filter: function(list) {
                return $.map(list, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
            }
        }
    });
countries.initialize();
$('input[name="member_country"].typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'countries',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: countries.ttAdapter()
    }).on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function (ev, datum) {
        console.log(datum);
    });
```

Any pointers on how I can compare the selected value with those present in the JSON I'm loading for the typeahead to check if it matches?

Comment: At what stage is it going to compare? While they are typing (constantly checking and then showing an error)? When they submit the form (and then showing an error)? Or will it not let them type the next letter unless it matches a string from your list?

Comment: Hmm, I think the ideal would be to check as they type and prevent entry of any value not in the JSON array. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some research and found [this issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/246) on github in which they pretty much say there is no way to do it using Typeahead / Bloodhound.

They recommend using the [Chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or the [Select2 jquery plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) both of which look like they will do exactly what you want them to do.

Also, while I was doing my daily research and found a plugin called [Magic Suggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/index.html) which is a little bit different and possibly not quite what you are trying to do, but might be worth looking at.

Hope my answer helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at both of those. As you say it seems probable that there is no real answer to this one. :)

Answer (score 3):

I found this thread whilst searching for the same answer. Decided to keep the library and add the functionality myself.

```
        $('.typeahead')
          .on('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
              $(ev.target).attr('data-value', suggestion);
          })
          .on('blur', function(ev) {
            var target = $(ev.target);
            target.val(target.attr('data-value'));
          })
          .on('typeahead:change', function(ev) {

            var target = $(ev.target),
                id = '.tt-dataset-' + ev.target.id + ' .tt-suggestion'; // visible suggestions div

            var suggestions = $(id).map(function() {return $(this).text();} ).get();
            var i = $.inArray(target.val(), suggestions);

            if(i >= 0) {
                target.attr('data-value', suggestions[i]);
            } else {
                target.attr('data-value', '');
            }

        })
```

Works thusly:

1. On **selecting** an option, set an attribute `data-value` to store the selected value.
2. On the field **losing focus**, set the field to `data-value` to force it back to a selected value (or empty, see 3).
3. On **change**, check to see if the field matches a visible suggestion. set `data-value` to suggestion if it does, otherwise empty attribute.

Could use another option as well, but adding these listeners could save you moving to a different library as @joshhunt suggested.